# Multiple Regression with repeated measure variables in R

Tags: r, regression

I have a questionnaire with 5 subscales and one g factor which was measured at baseline (T0) and I want to know if these scores predict the scores of a second questionnaire measured at a later time (T1)

I have one observation for each participant so my data looks like this:

```
test1_gfactor_T0 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
test2_T1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

I fit a linear model this way:

```
model <- lm(test2_T1 ~ test1_gfactor_T0)
```

However I'm not sure if this is correct, as the values are depending on each other because they come from the same subjects.

I also would like to add the 5 subscales in a second step (I guess this is hierarchical regression then) but I'm unsure if this poses further difficulties because of the repeated measures design.

Comment: we would need more data to help. are you aware of the packages lme4 or nlme

Comment: What data do you need? I only used the two vectors like I described just with real data. I tried using the lme4 package with function lmer but it didn´t work because I don´t have any between subject variables

Comment: what is the repeated measure then? with your vector above if you need to compare them maybe do a paired samples t-test or simply a correlation. What does it mean you would like to add 5 subscales?

Comment: The repeated measures comes from the fact that the first vector was acquired at an earlier time than the second factor but with the same subjects. If the context helps: I gave participants a trait questionnaire at T0 (Baseline) and want to see if these scores predict the scores of a state questionnaire I gave them at a later time (T1). So simply comparing is not enough as I am interested in a possible causal relationship. I would like to perform a hierarchical regression with first adding only the g-factor and then adding the subscales the test provides and see if the modelfit changes

Comment: I would suggest moving this question to stat exchange to get the statistical help and then we can help with the coding part